# Android emulator in Android Studio is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I Installed Android Studio. In Android Studio Import the existing android project and gradle build success and I run the Application by Launching new emulator. Emulator Details is:

```
    Name: Nexus_5_API_23_x86

    CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

    Path: C:\Users\Administrator\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_23_x86.avd

    Target: Google APIs (API level 23)

    Skin: nexus_5

    SD Card: 200M

    Snapshot: no

    hw.lcd.density: 480

    hw.dPad: no

    avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

    hw.camera.back: emulated

    disk.dataPartition.size: 200M

    hw.gpu.enabled: yes

    runtime.network.latency: none

    skin.dynamic: no

    hw.keyboard: no

    runtime.network.speed: full

    hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88

    hw.ramSize: 1536

    tag.id: google_apis

    tag.display: Google APIs

    hw.sdCard: no

    hw.device.manufacturer: Google

    hw.mainKeys: no

    hw.accelerometer: yes

    hw.trackBall: no

    hw.device.name: Nexus 5

    hw.sensors.proximity: yes

    hw.battery: yes

    AvdId: Nexus_5_API_23_x86

    hw.sensors.orientation: yes

    hw.audioInput: yes

    hw.camera.front: emulated

    hw.gps: yes

    avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 23 x86

    snapshot.present: no

    vm.heapSize: 64

    runtime.scalefactor: auto
```

Emulator was Started But App is not installed always shows Device connected: emulator-5554 under app tab. for a Long Time...
Any Solution? I am new to Android.

Answer (score 0):

One posible solution:

Once you run the emulator, run the app(shift + f10) again, this time in the device chooser under the choose a running device, your emulator must be visible, click it and done.